# Trying to use flexfit.loose in flutter but it is throwing an error , The argument type 'FlexFit' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use `flexfit.loose` in flutter, but it is throwing an error:

```
The argument type 'FlexFit' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'
```

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/transaction.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import './chart_bar.dart';
// import 'dart:html';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  // const Chart({super.key});
  final List<Transaction> recentTransactions;

  Chart(this.recentTransactions);

  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionsValues {
    return List.generate(7, (index) {
      final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
        Duration(days: index),
      );
      double totalSum = 0.0;
      for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
        if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
            recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
          totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
        }
      }

      return {
        'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
        'amount': totalSum,
      };
    });
  }

  double get totalSpending {
    return groupedTransactionsValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
      return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: groupedTransactionsValues.map((data) {
          //return Text(data['day'] + '+' + data['amount'].toString());
          return Flexible(
            flex: **FlexFit.loose**, // here is the error it is not working
            child: ChartBar(
                data['day'] as String,
                data['amount'] as double,
               (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was working with the flutter using the dart code, but the `flexfit.loose` was throwing an error message

I tried `flexfit.loose`, but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the `flex` parameter with the [`fit`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/fit.html) parameter.

Instead of:

```dart
Flexible(flex: FlexFit.loose)
```

should be the `fit` parameter:

```dart
Flexible(fit: FlexFit.loose)
```

---

- [flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) accepts an `int`
- [`fit`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/fit.html) accepts a [FlexFit](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/FlexFit.html)